# How do I create custom directives to protect my GraphQL API?

Tags: authorization, graphql

I want to use custom directives to protect my GraphQL API. More specifically, for specific GraphQL fields, I want to check if users have authorisation to query those fields when a request hits my GraphQL server.

The following links are articles that contain examples on achieving this objective.

- Link 1: https://www.prisma.io/blog/graphql-directive-permissions-authorization-made-easy-54c076b5368e/
- Link 2: https://codeburst.io/use-custom-directives-to-protect-your-graphql-apis-a78cbbe17355

However, both examples achieve this by first constructing their Schema using the GraphQL Schema Definition Language (below is a snippet from the [repo for Link 2](https://github.com/DavidHe1127/aws-cognito-example/blob/master/server/server.js)) that demonstrates how you can use custom directives to check if users have authorisation to query specific fields (such as "rating").

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');
const {
  makeExecutableSchema
} = require('graphql-tools');

const {directiveResolvers} = require('./directives');
const {allProductsBySupplier, addProduct, product, suppliers} = require('./resolvers');

require('./auth');

const app = express();

const port = 8080;
const typeDefs = `
  directive @isAuthenticated on QUERY | FIELD
  directive @hasScope(scope: [String]) on QUERY | FIELD
  type Product {
    id: ID!
    supplierId: ID!
    sku: String
    qty: Int
    price: Int
    parrot: String
    rating: Int @hasScope(scope: ["read:rating"])
  }
  type Supplier {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
  }
  input ProductInput {
    supplierId: ID!
    sku: String!
    qty: Int!
    price: Int!
    parrot: String!
    rating: Int!
  }
  type Query {
    allProductsBySupplier: [Product] @isAuthenticated
    product: Product @isAuthenticated
    suppliers: [Supplier]
  }
  type Mutation {
    addProduct(input: ProductInput!): Product @hasScope(scope: ["add:product"])
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    allProductsBySupplier,
    product,
    suppliers
  },
  Mutation: {
    addProduct
  }
};

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  directiveResolvers
});

app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    graphiql: true
  })
);

app.listen(port);

console.log(`server running on localhost:${port}`);
```

I have constructed my API without using the GraphQL schema definition language as shown below. The following snippet has been extracted from the [official graphql docs](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/constructing-types/).

```
var express = require('express');
var graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');
var graphql = require('graphql');

// Maps id to User object
var fakeDatabase = {
  'a': {
    id: 'a',
    name: 'alice',
  },
  'b': {
    id: 'b',
    name: 'bob',
  },
};

// Define the User type
var userType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: {
    id: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
    name: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
  }
});

// Define the Query type
var queryType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    user: {
      type: userType,
      // `args` describes the arguments that the `user` query accepts
      args: {
        id: { type: graphql.GraphQLString }
      },
      resolve: function (_, {id}) {
        return fakeDatabase[id];
      }
    }
  }
});

var schema = new graphql.GraphQLSchema({query: queryType});

var app = express();
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
  schema: schema,
  graphiql: true,
}));
app.listen(4000);
console.log('Running a GraphQL API server at localhost:4000/graphql');
```

**How can I create custom directives to check if users have authorisation to query specific fields if I have constructed my Schema without using the GraphQL Schema Definition Language?**

Comment: You might try looking at Ryan Chenkie's implementation of hasScopes [directive](https://about.sourcegraph.com/graphql/handling-authentication-and-authorization-in-graphql) and watch his talk [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_Bcw7BULC8)

Comment: Hi @user8888, I'm facing the same issue where I just can't seem to find documentation on directives without using the GraphQL Schema Definition Language. Were you able to figure it out?